# Wordpress : ReferrenceError $ not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using wordpress and trying to access this code snippet .It's Showing error in the last line }(jQuery));

```
(function($) {
  $(function () {
    // Slideshow 3
    $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
      auto: true,
      pager:true,
      nav:false,
      speed: 500,
      namespace: "callbacks",
      before: function () {
        $(".events").append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
      },
      after: function () {
        $(".events").append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
      }
    }); 
  });
}(jQuery));
```

It's showing Referrence error as : $ not defined .I have searched in stackoverflow but din't found a correct solution.Please let me know where i am doing wrong.
**Note : I have placed my main Jquery script above all so that it gets included first before any other script.**

Comment: Where exactly in the line is it showing. Looks like all the references are good for you!

Comment: If your _jQuery_ URI is failing to load (or is _async'd or deferred_) then this could cause the issue even though it's earlier in the tree

Comment: @PaulS.: Not true. You'd get a "ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined." It is impossible to receive a `Referrence error as : $ not defined` error within the given code snippet. The error must be elsewhere in the OP's code.

Comment: A simple test is to change all $ to jQuery.

Comment: @PraveenKumar  : I have updated my question referring to exactly in which line the error is fired.

Comment: The comment by @Matt is perfect.

Comment: Please use English punctuation when writing in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this is how I setup a javascript file using WordPress.

Add this code to either your header or footer, depending on the application makes a difference:

```
<script type="application/x-javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        your_javascript_function('add any variables here');
    });
</script>
```

Then I would modify your script to look like this:

```
function your_javascript_function(vars) {
    // Slideshow 3
    $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
      auto: true,
      pager:true,
      nav:false,
      speed: 500,
      namespace: "callbacks",
      before: function () {
        $(".events").append("<li>before event fired.</li>");
      },
      after: function () {
        $(".events").append("<li>after event fired.</li>");
      }
    });
  }
```

If you are still receiving an error try adding a $ to the js here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

If that doesn't work change all $ to jQuery.

If that doesn't work then something else is causing your issues.

Comment: After following your instructions , it gives jQuery not defined error. what should i check now sir ?

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala Check your debugger and make sure you see that jQuery has been loaded.

Comment: It is getting loaded sir , infact some jquery scripts are running fine , but this one only is showing error.

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala where is your document ready script located?

Comment: :first it was in my footer file in functions.php but i then tried to separete it out in new js file and stored it in js folder . i just call it from the footer but still the error remains as it is.

Comment: how exactly are you calling it from the footer?

Comment: I have solved the error by replacing the script with similar plugin. Thank you @Ian , i learned many things from your suggestions.

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala no problem glad I could point you in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

How about enqueue_script function? Have your tried that? Or how is your js embedded?

```
function mytheme_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', $child_uri . '/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', $child_uri . '/js/YOURSCRIPT' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_style' );
```

Comment: wp_register_script( 'jquery-1.11.1.min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-1.11.1.min');

Comment: WordPress includes jQuery by default. There's no reason to re-enqueue it.

Comment: oh okay so just ignore the second line.